# Hashing in dictionary in kdb

Tags: kdb

When we read through Q for Mortals(Dictionary section) there is a description that:
**When you know that the keys are unique you can apply the `u# attribute to the keys. This will effectively cause the dictionary to be a hash table with the attendant improvement in lookup speed over the default linear lookup.**

Can someone please let me know how is this dictionary is converted to hashtable behind the scenes?

As we know that in Java an array of 16 buckets in maintained for hashtable and a hash function generates the location and the element is placed in that bucket and a linkedlist/tree is maintained in case of collision.

Just want to understand how the conversion from dictionary to hashtable is done in kdb?

Practically applying unique attribute to keys make the searching way faster.

```
Eg:
q)a:(`u#asc -100000?`6)!100000?10 / hashtable
q)b:(-100000?`6)!100000?10

// Searching elements in dictionary which is converted to hashtable
q)\t:100000 a[(key a)[1021]]
24
q)\t:100000 a[(key a)[2231]]
25
q)\t:100000 a[(key a)[72461]]
24
q)\t:100000 a[(key a)[89985]]
24

//Searching elements in dictionary which is not converted to hashtable
q)\t:100000 b[(key b)[1021]]
51
q)\t:100000 b[(key b)[2231]]
90
q)\t:100000 b[(key b)[72461]]
2642
q)\t:100000 b[(key b)[89985]]
3280
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of the hash table is not exposed to the user so you're unlikely to find out how it's done behind the scenes. Also the hash table isn't created out of the dictionary, it's created only for the list which forms the key of your dictionary.

Your dictionary lookup requires a lookup of the keys (a list) - the u# attribute speeds up the searching of said list by not defaulting to using linear search.

Some info here: http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/table-attributes#unique-attribute